# Adjust the size of inline datepicker in jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using a jquery UI inline datepicker. No matter what I do, no matter in what screen size I run the program, the size of the datepicker is always considerably bigger than what I want it to be.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
<li draggable="true" class="list" id="g1">goof</li>
<div id="gc1" class="datepicker hasDatepicker">
.
.
.
```

This whole content is created dynamically in js:

```
var container = document.createElement("div");
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    node.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    node.setAttribute("class", "list");         
    node.setAttribute('id','g'+i);
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("goof");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    container.appendChild(node);
    //Calendar
    var cal = document.createElement("div");
    cal.setAttribute('id','gc'+i);
    cal.setAttribute("class","datepicker");
    //cal (calendar) part of the container
    container.appendChild(cal);
    //container is a part of the list
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(container);
```

I have tried to directly change the width of the datepicker, tried altering it relative to it's parents and siblings. But nothing worked. What should I do?

Comment: Can you post your code in fiddle?

Comment: @tilda Not getting the output in fiddle. don't know why.